# URL Type for Lighting:Datatable opens in new tab in console navigation

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable, navigation, workspaceapi

I'd like to have my datatable links open in a new sub tab when my users are using console navigation, but somehow they always open in a new tab.

Here's the column definition for the link field:

```
  { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Link', type: 'url', 
typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name'}, target: '_blank'}},
```

I considered using the [WorkspaceAPI component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation):, but I don't see how I can catch the click event before the tab opens.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you post code how currently open the tab? r u using `oppenSubtab` or `openTab`?

Comment: @sdandamud1 I'm not using any code -it's a built in lightning-datatable column type. I'll add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `target` attribute inside `typeAttributes` , as part of the column definition for your data table. Here's an example of hyperlinking the Case Number column in a Case data table:

```
{
    label: 'Case Number', 
    fieldName: 'URL',
    type: 'url', 
    typeAttributes: { 
        label: {
            fieldName: 'CaseNumber'
        },
        target: '_self'
    },
    sortable: true 
}
```

Using `_self` as the target opens a new console tab when used in the context of a Console application. The default behavior opens a new browser tab.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Not that I know of. I just figured it out by experiment, I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidReed  thanks for your inputs. in the context of a console app: don't know if the behavior has changed since your answer, but when using "_self", a new browser tab opened and then the page displays as a console tab in the new browser page. to workaround this I've used "_parent" instead, which then works fine and opens the page directly in a console tab of current page